# text for h1 tag is not showing in browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to display text in `h1` tags but only about but `about.js` displays text. First one is `shop.js` component and second file is `app.js` file.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function Shop() {
return (
 <div>
   <h1>Shop page</h1>
 </div>
);
}
export default Shop;
```

My `App` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Nav from './Nav';
import Shop from './Shop';
import About from './About';
import Home from './Home';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Switch,Route} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
 return (
 <Router>
  <div className="App">
    <Nav />
    <Switch>
      <Router path="/" exact component={Home} />
     
      <Route path="/about"component={About} />

      <Router path="/shop"  component={Shop} />
      
    </Switch>
  </div>
  </Router>
  );
}      

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you rendering the `Shop` component somewhere, e.g. as `<Shop />`?

Comment: No @weltschmerz

Comment: Do you `export default Shop;`?

Comment: yes I have written that

Comment: What do you put in `About.js` then?

Comment: About.js has the same code Shop.js except for the text within h1 tag.

Comment: How about filename `shop.js` vs `Shop.js`?

Answer (score 0):

try adding `shop` route before `home` route like this:

```
<Route path="/about"component={About} />
<Router path="/shop"  component={Shop} />
<Router path="/" exact component={Home} />
```

i have created a code expample  [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-allen-f3126?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: only about component displays text, home and shop component doesn't.

Comment: @adel In your example, order doesn't matter.

Comment: @ TimTim Wong yes you are right  if we remove exact from order will mater .

Answer (score 0):

Your routes and the `Shop` component itself look fine, so I'm guessing you just forgot to export the Shop component:

```js
export function Shop() {
  return (
   <div>
     <h1>Shop page</h1>
   </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I have actually that. like **export default Shop;**

Comment: If `Shop` is undefined, `App` wouldn't load at all.

Comment: @laraib.j can you do `console.log(Shop)` before you run `function App() { ...` and tell us what it logs?

Comment: If you run `console.log('hello')` at the same place instead, does that log "hello"?